# Why would height specified as 1.0em be slightly less than font-size instead of equal?

Tags: css

Consider the following display from the Chrome debugger showing the styles on an element:

```
font-size: 18px;
height: 17.600000381469727px;
    .a, .h, .r - 1.0em
left: 52.80000305175781px;
line-height: 17.600000381469727px;
    .a, .h, .r - 1.0em
```

My understanding is that since height is specified as 1.0em, then its value in pixels should precisely equal to the font-size; instead it's 0.4 pixels smaller for some reason. There are no effects of padding or margin.

The confusing thing is that in an earlier version things were working fine:

```
font-size: 18px;
height: 18px;
    .stone, .iw-capture - 1em
line-height: 18px;
    .stone, .mark, .iw-capture - 1.0em
```

So there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the browser's ability to do math. However, I can't figure out what changed to result in the odd behavior, or for that matter why anything changing should have an effect on this.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening or what I'm missing?

Comment: I thought an em was a measure of width?

Comment: I think height of text in different fonts is different in equal font-size

Comment: Please clarify what the relevant source code is and what data is from Chrome debugger, in a manner that allows the issue to be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

The formula to calculate the `em` is

```
1 ÷ parent font size (px) × required pixels = em equivalent
```

As you can see dividing `1` by `18` in your case will give you a very long float which later is being multiplied by `18` - and it won't give you the exact same integer. That's the browser's math engine..

Comment: I believe em is relative to parent font size only for the font-size property; for other properties, it is interpreted in terms of the font size on the element itself. Quote: "the font-relative lengths refer to the computed font metrics of the *element on which they are used*. The exception is when they occur in the value of the ‘font-size’ property itself, in which case they refer to the font metrics of the parent element." However, I don't think this has anything to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is using for some reason the line-height of the element.